# Creating a function that is always visible, regardless of userpath?

Tags: matlab

I want to write a function that can always be called, no matter what the current userpath is.

I thought I might make a new directory called "custom" within `matlabroot/toolbox/`, and then place any custom functions within this directory, but [Mathworks advises against this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/files-and-folders-that-matlab-accesses.html).

Where should this function be stored, and how can it be made to be always visible, regardless of the userpath?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `SetPath` in the main window of MATLAB to include your "custom" folder to the MATLAB search path:

[image]

It doesn't matter where the folder is located.

Comment: @user31360 Please consider accepting the answer then (tick mark on the top left corner of the answr text)